# Ruby make 1.8 Hash#select behave like 1.9 Hash#select

Tags: ruby, hashmap

In Ruby 1.9: `{1=>2,3=>4}.select{|k,v| v>2}` gives `{3=>4}`

In Ruby 1.8: `{1=>2,3=>4}.select{|k,v| v>2}` gives `[[3,4]]`

How can I write a simple piece of code that will give `{3=>4}` in both 1.9 *and* 1.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Hash[{1=>2,3=>4}.select{|k,v| v>2}]
```